# Qual o fluxo de compilação da .NET framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net, vb.net

Eu estou iniciando a minha caminhada no .NET. Estou a programar em ASP.net mas não consigo compreender como um projecto em asp.net se transforma em html + javascript. Suponho que haja um processo de compilação por trás disto.

Para além disto gostaria de saber em **Model Control View** quais os ficheiros responsaveis por cada uma destas tarefas?
No meu caso a view será o aspx, o control e o model será o vb.net.
Estarei certo?

Podem partilhar o vosso conhecimento?

Obrigado

Comment: Pedro C., sugiro que você estude algumas páginas na teia de computadores. Exemplos: [ASP .NET 4.5 Web Forms - Criando o Projeto - I (Início do Curso)](http://www.macoratti.net/Cursos/aspnet45/aspn_451.htm) [ASP .NET Core - Criando uma aplicação ASP .NET Core MVC com o VS 2017](http://www.macoratti.net/17/04/aspcore_mvcfilme1.htm) [ASP .NET Core 2.0 - MiniCurso Básico](http://www.macoratti.net/Cursos/aspncore2_mcurso1.htm) [Curso de ASP NET com MVC - Aula 01 - ASP.NET C# e MVC](https://youtu.be/TMDHfcim87k)

Answer (score 0):

**MVC:** Model, View, Controller.

**Model**: Camada de lógica da aplicação é onde você colocará a regra de negócios da sua aplicação(utilizando o C# ou vb.net por exemplo) é aqui que você gerencia dados, lógica e as regras da aplicação.

**View**: Responsável pela exibição da sua página, precisa ser compilado em tempo real, após isso gera um HTML.A codificação se da através da linguagem de programação você conseguirá popular o HTML com os dados trazidos do Controller.

**Controller**: É onde as requisições são processadas, captura os dados recebidos afim de passa-las para o Model que responderá com dados(se necessário), uma vez recebido os dados, o Controller deverá responder seja retornando dados brutos através de `JSON` por exemplo ou retornando uma View com dados.

Como funciona o ciclo na prática? (Exemplo em ASP.NET MVC C#)

- O usuário acessa a página *www.google.com* e digitará *StackOverflow*;

1° O **Controller** receberá um **Model** com os dados inseridos no formulário da página do Google.

```
public ActionResult Index(SearchModel search) //Passo 1 - A pesquisa se encontra dentro do Model enviado para o Controller
{
    search.SearchResponse = search.Search(); //Passo 2 - Método Search() retorna o objeto SearchResponse para dentro da própria classe SearchModel
    return View(search); //Passo 3 - O model é retornado para a camada de visualização (View)
}
```

2° O **Model** quando chamado através do **Controller** processa a lógica e responde com o que foi solicitado.

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public String SearchInput {get;set;}
    public SearchResponse SearchResponse {get;set;}

    public SearchResponse Search()
    {
        //Lógica do método Search
    }
}
```

3° A **View** processa os dados trazidos do **Controller** que foram processados no **Model**.

```
<body>
    @foreach(SearchResult result in Model.SearchResponse.SearchResult)
    {
        <p>@result.Description</p> 
    }

</body>
```

4° O navegador do usuário recebe o seguinte:

```
<body>
    <p>Stack Overflow é um website de capital fechado, o site principal da Rede Stack Exchange. Foi criado em 2008 por Jeff Atwood e Joel Spolsky como uma ...</p>

    <p>Over the weekend, there was an attack on Stack Overflow. We have confirmed that some level of production access was gained on May...</p>  
</body>
```

São só exemplos práticos de respostas, o HTML é retornado de forma completa(com `<html>`,`<head>` e tudo mais que foi setado no seu Layout)

[Nessa página](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/mvc) da Microsoft também da para ter uma noção básica de como as coisas funcionam.